# How to have my background in a fixed position?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, background, css-position

I use ionic 3.
My background is moving, I don't want it to scroll.
How to have my background in a fixed position ?

```css
<style>
          #back {
             background-size: 100%;
             background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
             background-size: cover!important;
             width: 105vw!important;
             height: 100vh!important;
             margin-left: -10%!important;
             background-attachment: fixed!important;
             margin-top: -10%!important;
             background-position: center center!important;
           }
</style>
```

```html
          #back {
            background-size: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 105vw;
            height: 105vh;
            margin-left: -10%;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            margin-top: -10%;
            background-position: center center;
          }
          
          .ion-content {
            background: url('../assets/imgs/back.png');
          }
```

Comment: My problem has been resolved below. Thank you @G-Cyr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `position` attribute.

```
<style>
      #back {
         background-size: 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
         background-size: cover!important;
         width: 105vw!important;
         height: 100vh!important;
         margin-left: -10%!important;
         background-attachment: fixed!important;
         margin-top: -10%!important;
         background-position: center center!important;
         position: fixed;
       }
</style>
```

Comment: It's ok, but I had buttons on my page they disappeared.
Do you know why ?

Comment: Try using z-index: -1; for #back in your style tag. Maybe some elements are getting hidden by the fixed position.